# Regex grouping whether string is there or not

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of strings that are like:

```
Bought MSFT@Arca ABCD
Bought Yahoo@Nasdaq 
Sold Google@Nasdaq ABCD
```

I want to create a dataframe of ABCD for all the strings.

So the desired dataframe should say something like:

```
ACBD
NaN
ABCD
```

How can I parse the strings out first using regex? I tried `(ABCD|)` but that returns blank.

Comment: What have you tried already? If you want to use regex, did you check https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html python's re documentation?

Comment: you can use `split` and then take the last element

Comment: You can use `@\w+[ \t]+(\w+)?`. If there's no capture group, you know it's `NaN`

Comment: Wouldn't be better to take the last 4 chars of the string and check if it is `== "ABCD"`?

Answer (score 1):

As a whole snippet:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

string = """Bought MSFT@Arca ABCD
Bought Yahoo@Nasdaq 
Sold Google@Nasdaq ABCD"""

needle = 'ABCD'

def search(line):
    return needle if line.endswith(needle) else np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame((search(line) for line in string.split("\n")))

print(df)
```

This makes use of `.endswith()`, a function `search()` and a list comprehension and will yield

```
      0
0  ABCD
1   NaN
2  ABCD
```

Even shorter using a lambda function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(map(lambda x: needle if x.endswith(needle) else np.nan, string.split("\n")))
print(df)
```

For a more individual solution, you'd need to elaborate on the actual input strings.